# Site loading speed & Bootstrap "Carousel" images loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Does Bootstrap "Carousel" load all images at one time? If so, does it reduce site loading speed and increase loading time?

I do not know how Bootstrap Carousel javascript file works. When next icon is  clicked, if next image is loaded via ajax, there is no problem. But  if all images are loaded at one time, I think it reduces page speed.

Any idea?

Comment: Using your browser console network tab should answer your first question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bootstrap carousel just rotates it's items. If images are defined by `src` attribute, images will be loaded with the rest of the page.

You can use some lazy loading solutions to load images sequentially - [Google search](https://www.google.ru/#newwindow=1&q=bootstrap+carousel+lazy+load+images)

Comment: This is now the top result, May be worth updating the answer to actual code ?

Comment: @user1281385, you might want to read the question one more time.

Comment: You link to the google search which this page is now the top hit. Adding an example of lazy loading would still work with the answer

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap does not do any magic lazy loading behind the scenes as Tigran points out. However, many browsers do not request images that are hidden through "display:none". So when inspecting network traffic with, for example the Chrome browser, you will see that the images are in practice "lazily" loaded.

An outdated and almost unreadable list of browsers with this behaviour can be found here: http://www.w3.org/2009/03/image-display-none/results